# Text Wrap in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, expo

I am trying to wrap the text inside of a `<Text>` (red background), but it is not working. I have tried to use `flexWrap: wrap`. See below for the component code (functional component) and styling (at the end of the snipped inside the `styles` constant.

[image]

```
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const ChatListItem = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: "https://notjustdev-dummy.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/avatars/lukas.jpeg",
        }}
        style={styles.image}
      />
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>lukas</Text>
          <Text style={styles.time}>4:00</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>
          abideabide abideabide abideabide abideabide abideabide abideabide
          abideabide abideabide abideabide abideabide abideabide
          abideabideabideabid
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    marginVertical: 10,
    height: 70,
  },
  image: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    marginRight: 15,
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  name: {
    flex: 1,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  time: {
    color: "gray",
  },
  subTitle: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
});

export default ChatListItem;
```

Thank you for your help with the problem above.

Answer (score 2):

Adding flexShrink: 1 and removing the height property from the style produced an acceptable result.
[image]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    marginVertical: 10,
    flexShrink: 1,
  },
  image: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    marginRight: 15,
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  name: {
    flex: 1,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  time: {
    color: "gray",
  },
  subTitle: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What does it look like when you say the text doesn't wrap? Perhaps the `subTitle` component needs a fixed width defined, e.g. `width: 100`

Comment: Added an image for illustration.